# Is this statement true or false? Find its negation.

Tags: logic

> Consider the statement
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\;\forall y \in \mathbb{R}\ x+y>0$$
> Is this statement true or false? Also, find its negation.

I think this statement is false because the inequality is not always true; for example, for $y=-x$, the inequality is false.

Can you show me how to write the solution in the proper way?

Comment: To show that the statement above is false, you simply need to prove that its negation is true.  You've found an $x$ and $y$ so that $x + y \le 0$, so done.

Comment: When $x=1$, $y=-2$ we have $x+y=-1<0$. Therefore the statement is false.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: One example *verifies* a statement, doesn't *prove* it.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 the negated statement starts with a quantifier "there exists", so one example does prove it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

Since for $x=-1$ and $y=-1$, $(-1)+(-1)=-2>0$ is false. So, the given statement is false.

Clearly, the negation is:
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}\ x+y\leq0$$

---

**DISCUSSION**

1. To show that the statement is false, we just need one counterexample and we are done.
2. To find the negation, remember that the negative of "for all" is "there exists" and that of $>$ is $\ngtr$ or $\leq$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: I'd choose $x=y=0$ ...

Comment: @MichaleHoppe: People are exercising their freedom of choice of counterexample lol.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of contradiction, assume the statement holds true.

Next, we fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and set $y = -x$. Observe that from our contradiction assumption, we have
\begin{align*}
x + y &>0\\
x + (-x)&>0\\
0 &>0
\end{align*}
However, this is impossible and hence it is a contradiction. Therefore, the statement must be false.